# Use django-cms with VueJS broke the front-end editing

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vuejs2, django-cms

I try to create a sample app using django-cms and VueJS.

```
<body>
    {% cms_toolbar %}
    <div class="container">
        <div id="vue-wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% render_block "js" %}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script>
        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#vue-wrapper',
            mounted: () => {
                console.log("mounted")
            },
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

This simple code broke the front-end editing.

If I remove the vue-wrapper element, comment the js code, or close the element before it wrapping my content, the front-end editing works.

I don't understand why wrapping with Vue broke this, and if it's possible, how I can fix.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but fo not use `=>` functions ith mounted just use `mounted:function(){}` because it will cause a scoping isuue with `this`

Comment: I know it, but i don't use use this in the body of the function so, isn't an issue.

And don't solve the problem...

But thank you  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because django-cms uses the `<template>` tags to wrap it's plugins into .cms-plugin div's when in structure mode.
That adds the double click to edit link to the actual plugin.

Since Vue uses the `<template>` tags to specify templates outside javascript, it parses them and remove's their content.
Thats why the "double click to edit" feature is gone.

I've wrote a simple patch for this that wraps django-cms plugins in `<cms-template>` tags which when included in `Vue.config.ignoredElements` ensure the cms-plugin div's remain after vue have processed the html.

You can find the patch here:
https://gist.github.com/dinoperovic/a719f0c43a2614f434a309b64a64e18f

Simply load the script and do this in your js:

```
// app.js

// Set ignored elements as required by vue-djangocms-patch.
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['cms-template', 'cms-plugin'];

// Main Vue instance.
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created: function () {
    new VueDjangoCMSPatch(this);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Dino.